# Searching Linked List

Tags: c++, search, linked-list

I tried this code several times and also wrote it in both iterative and recursive versions but unable to catch the mistake. The function returns a pointer to a Node element in the linked list and returns nullptr if it is not present in the list.

````
    ListNode<T>* contains(const T& obj)
    {

        return contains(head, obj);
    }
    ListNode<T>* contains(ListNode<T>* itr,const T& obj)
    {
        if (itr == nullptr) return nullptr;
        if (itr->data == obj) return itr;
        return contains(itr->next, obj);
    }
    ListNode<T>* contains(T& obj)
    {
        ListNode<T>* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr && temp->data != obj)
            temp = temp->next;

        return temp;
    }```
````

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: When I use it in a function of Hash Tables, the program crashes if the obj is not present else works fine in all situations.

Comment: so compile it for debug and run under your debugger

Comment: Presumably, the caller of `contains` is not prepared for it returning `nullptr`. To the extent there is a problem, it likely lies in the code not shown. Prepare a [mcve].

Comment: I thought in c++   -99 % 10 would be 1 since -99 = 10*(-10) + 1. But it was -9. This was the problem